# Why variables' address on stack are not sequential

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

(I do this test on Windows Visual Studio 2019 Version16.7)

```
    const char a = 'a';
    const char b = 'b';
    const char c = 'a';

    intptr_t ptr_a = (intptr_t)&a;
    intptr_t ptr_b = (intptr_t)&b;
    intptr_t ptr_c = (intptr_t)&c;

    std::cout << ptr_b - ptr_a << "  " << ptr_c - ptr_b << std::endl;
```

if I run this piece of code under Debug, the result is:
"32 32"

if I run this piece of code under release, the reuslt is:
"-1 2"

So, the question is:
sizeof(char) is 1, but why we get "32 32", the address on stack should be continuous，right?
And, under release mode, why ptr_b is less than ptr_a?

Comment: `the address on stack should be continuous，right?` - wrong, the language standard does not dictate that (moreover, it does not even state that local variables should be implement using a stack to begin with).

Comment: Note that an optimizing compiler can detect that you do not actually _use_ `&a` so the value can be any unique number. It only has to be a "real" stack address when you use it as such.

Comment: @MSalters The optiminzing compiler will omit these not actually used variables. but, the &a has been used in the std::cout statement.

Answer (score 7):

> the address on stack should be continuous，right?

No, there is no requirement on the relationship between addresses of variables that are not part of the same array, or object. They don't have to be contiguous, or anything like that. Also, as far as the language is concerned, there doesn't even have to be a stack.

In fact, doing any pointer arithmetic on these pointers will invoke undefined behavior. You are allowed to compare the pointers for equality though.

Comment: Methinks you are allowed to write `if (&a == &b)` even if they are not objects in the same array.

Comment: @Bathsheba You're absolutely right. Edited the answer, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The addresses on stack should keep increase or decrease. They growth towards the same direction. It's weird to understand this kind of  chaotic addresses.

Comment: Yes, that's an interesting question. But it's not a c++ question really.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard only requires objects to be contiguous in memory if they are in the same array.

That's not the case in your example.

The behaviour of `intptr_t ptr_a = (intptr_t)&a;` is *implementation defined*. The value of `ptr_b - ptr_a` is implementation defined too.

(Note that the value of `&b - &a` is *undefined*.)

Comment: Actually, I just want to get the direction of address growth on stack, increasing or decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, the variables are not inside an array, so they are not required to be in contiguous memory.

Also, since the variables are labeled as `const`, they can be placed in read-only memory, or in the data section of your executable.

Also, be aware that their locations may change due to optimization levels.

Comment: Thansk for your help. Maybe the compiler do this for security.